# Require Summary Tag for Methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

I'm trying to setup Code Analysis in my Visual Studio 2012 to require all methods have a  tag in comments above the method.

Does anyone know of a Code-Analysis rule that will do this?  Is there also a rule that will require the  tag for classes and class fields?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You mean a *specific* comment tag or an actual xml comment block?

Comment: The actual xml comment block. I want to make sure that all the code is commented before it will build/allowed to be checked in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StyleCop has a number of rules in this area - I'd recommend checking that out if you need to do this kind of analysis. For example: http://www.stylecop.com/docs/Documentation%20Rules.html

You can download the tool from http://stylecop.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Ian, I'll give this a quick try right now.  It looks like this should work.  Thanks!